# Can´t mount win8 partition in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mount, ntfs, automount, windows-8

After installing Win8 and then used WIMI to install Ubuntu. The operative systems work fine, now to my trouble.

I Can´t mount win8 partition in Ubuntu 12.04.
Is this a known error?
How can I fix this?

Comment: WIMI? Do you mean Wubi?

Comment: try to execute this

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g - o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdXZ /path/to/dir`, where XZ is your partition. for example /dev/sda1

Comment: remove hiberfile fixed everything! Great thanx

Comment: same problem. it says that w8 is hibernating and i can only mount as read only. but i already check the windows, and it has been properly shout down. any suggestions?